# Game sites that provide good community support for that game

Tags: community-management, support

What are examples of games sites that provide good community support for that game? That is, sites for a specific game that provide ways for players of that game for to ask questions, exchange information, publish results.

A site supporting a game could provide ways for both beginners and experts to interact with games producers and players and to explore the set of notions evoked by the game.

Comment: You mean a community site managed by users, or a site managed by the game developer/publisher?

Comment: Are you looking for some tool or something for managing your community? Or looking for examples of places that have communities. If it is the latter, you should be looking at http://gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry the question was ambiguous . I've edited hoping to make it clearer. I mean a site managed by the game developer/publisher.

Comment: @axel22, we are a game **development** site, not a game **support** site. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for a new elevated Web 2.0 developer-player relationships, or a developer's site with really tight integration between the multiplayer/social media/community connectivity and the developer's newsreel?

The sites that come to mind for various reasons:

- [Bungie.Net](http://www.bungie.net/) - The original pioneer in getting down and dirty with its playerbase in the AAA space via the Weekly Update, having a designated community rep (Frankie), and beating everyone to the chase when it comes to displaying Xbox Live stats on a website.
- [MuseGames](http://musegames.com/) - For one of their first big Unity games, Guns of Icarus, they built a whole community site backend designed to have even more games plugged into it for connectivity.
- [Battle.net](http://us.battle.net/en/) - All the new Facebook integration and combining all your product keys in one and even offering setup files for download was a big step.
- [Steam](http://steampowered.com) - Not for a specific game or developer, but still, a great model.
- [Wolfire Games](http://www.wolfire.com/) - A good study of the importance of constant, reliable and interesting updates for indie games in development, as well as exerting leadership in the indie community via the Humble Bundle.